# Laravel - set alias to the guard (auth)

Tags: php, laravel, class, authentication, static

So I have a custom guard called `guest` this is different from the default one (which I also use) called `user`.

Everything is working great, I'm accessing the guest eloquent model via:

```
Auth::guard('guest')->user; // this will return the guest user
```

And the user like:

```
Auth::user(); // this will return the "user"
```

I wonder if there is a way to register this new guard so I can access it like:

```
Auth::guest();
```

just like how I can access `user`? I can't find anything on the [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.html)

Comment: Wonder why you are creating custom guard with default (`guest`) name

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Are you registering new guard in `guards` array of `config/auth.php` by the name of `guest` because Laravel is using `guest` guard for unauthenticated users

Comment: yes, hmmm is that so? I havent seen it in the documentation anywhere\

Comment: Sorry `guest` is not guard, its a middleware, See: App/Http/Kernel.php file there is route Middleware registered under the name of `guest` to redirect login requests if user is already logged in.